# Split comma separated values into respective rows in SQL or SSIS.?

Tags: sql, ssis

Is it achievable in SQL or SSIS..?

[image]

Comment: Storing serialized datas goes against the purpose of having an RDBMS.

Comment: You should consider to make your table atomic (like it’s shown in one of your images. You could change Id to groupid (or something similar) and add a new primary key. So you could select the values by groupid and don’t „lose“ any information.

Comment: The answer to your question is "YES"

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE for this:

```
with cte as (
      select id, cast(NULL as varchar(max)) as grp, cast(NULL as varchar(max)) as cat,
             cast(grp + ',' as varchar(max)) as rest_grp, cast(cat + ',' as varchar(max)) as rest_cat, 0 as lev
      from t
      union all
      select  id, left(rest_grp, charindex(',', rest_grp) - 1), left(rest_cat, charindex(',', rest_cat) - 1),
              stuff(rest_grp, 1, charindex(',', rest_grp), ''), stuff(rest_cat, 1, charindex(',', rest_cat), ''), lev + 1
      from cte
      where rest_grp <> ''
     )
select id, grp, cat
from cte
where lev > 0
union all
select id, grp, cat
from t
where grp is null;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=085d8433baab7361c90d96e2ab4b8a74) is a db<>fiddle.